# Capybara + Sorcery helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, sorcery

I'm currently working on a project using Sorcery to authenticate users and I have some integration tests done with capybara. When I call **current_user** or **logged_in?** sorcery helpers I get this error:

```
ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments calling `page` (0 for 1)
```

but when I call them in development mode, it doesn't happen.

After some research I found out that the problem comes from find_by_id method. So if I call **Model.find_by_id(1)**, I get this error. I am very confused because I cannot understand why page method is called and where.

I fixed it by overriding the find_by_id method of my model, but I completely disagree doing this way, so...

Does anybody know what's going on?

Thank you in advance guys

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it. The problem was that I included Capybara in my env.rb so my ActiveRecord class were inheriting Capybara methods and find_by_id method for finding elements in a webpage was run instead of ActiveRecord find_by_id.

After deleting "include Capybara" line everything works fine.